# Show keyboard with button have symbol "#+=" as default

Tags: iphone

I want when I touch on a textfield, it will show the keyboard has symbol like: "[,],{,}..."
But I look into the delegate and try all types but it doesn't have that keyboard type.

I have searched about that but I can find a solution. So is it possible?

Comment: i'm honestly not sure what you're talking about, but if you're atlking about having a custom keyboard with certain custom buttons, look into inputView and inputAccessoryView

Comment: On the ios default keyboard you will see a button with label "123" it will appear number keyboard, and on it have a button with label "#+=". I want to set that keyboard type as default keyboard when user tap on textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default keyboards to show only the special characters. You can have "Numbers and Punctuation" keyboard as close.

The best solution is to have the custom input view for your textfield.

Create a view with the button you would like to have, and set that view as the `inputView` of your textfield.

```
    myTextField.inputView = myCustomView;
```

Add `IBAction` for the buttons and place the below code.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)btn {
    [self.currentActiveTextField insertText:btn.titleLabel.text];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following type of keyborad are available , you can choose any of them as per your need.
1.) ASCII Capable
2.) Number and Punctuation
3.) URL
4.) Number Pad
5.) Phone Pad
6.) Name Phone Pad
7.) E-mail Pad
8.) Decimal Pad
9.) Twitter